# keep unmasking image on mask animation

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am trying to make an effect where at first the entire screen is masked out. As a ball moves across the screen, the ball unmasks the area that it is in AND the areas that it WAS in remain unmasked.

I have the following code:

```
CALayer * ball = [CALayer layer];
ball.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 42, 42);
ball.position = [[[alphabet controls] objectAtIndex:0] CGPointValue];
ball.contents = (id)([UIImage imageNamed:@"done.png"].CGImage);
[self.layer addSublayer:ball];

[self.layer setMask:ball];

CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
anim.path = path;
anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
anim.duration = 8.0;
[ball addAnimation:anim forKey:@"race"];
```

This animation masks the entire view and shows only what is behind the ball layer.
My question is : How can I keep unmasked the parts of the screen that were revealed?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.

What you want is an image that contains all the pixels that the ball shape traveled through.

If you were animating the ball with frame-based animation, you could create a grayscale (or 1-bit) image and install that as the content of your mask layer. Then, as you moved the ball, you could draw it into your mask image with each frame.

I'm not sure how to get the same effect with Core animation.

You could make your mask a CAShapeLayer, create a CGPath that describes the entire path of your ball, and make that the path for your shape layer. If your ball is round, you could set the line thickness of the shape layer to your ball size. That would work. If you ball is an irregular shape, though, that approach wouldn't work. Quartz graphics on iOS doesn't have any way I know of to stroke a path with an arbitrary-shaped brush.